# coffeescript - array initialisation

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following code that obviously works but I am fairly sure there is a more terse way of expressing this in coffeescript:

```
  todos = []

  for i in [1..10]                                                                            
    todos.push App.store.find App.Todo, i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
todos = (App.store.find(App.Todo, i) for i in [1..10])
```

The enclosing parentheses indicate a [list comprehension](http://coffeescript.org/#loops), which collects the return values into an array and returns it.

Consider the two following examples. The enclosing parentheses change how Coffeescript interprets the loop.

```
# With parentheses (list comprehension)
todos = (App.store.find(App.Todo, i) for i in [1..10])

# Without parentheses (plain old loop)
todos = App.store.find(App.Todo, i) for i in [1..10]
```

And the output:

```
// With parentheses
todos = (function() {
  var _i, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 10; i = ++_i) {
    _results.push(App.store.find(App.Todo, i));
  }
  return _results;
})();

// Without parentheses
for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 10; i = ++_i) {
  todos = App.store.find(App.Todo, i);
}
```

Comment: The parentheses alter what CoffeeScript considers the body of the loop to be, not whether or not it will evaluate to an array (consider what [this loop](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20%3D%20-%3E%20c%20%3D%20b%20for%20b%20in%20a%0A) compiles to). The loop won't be arrayified if the compiler detects that the array won't be used (as in [this loop](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20%3D%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20c%20%3D%20b%20for%20b%20in%20a%0A%20%20%20%2011%0A)).